# Match element from collections, different type, common element

Tags: swift, performance

I have two collections, (say, `Set` and `Array`). Each has an `Object/Struct` of different type, but both have some `primary key`.

```
struct A {
    var name: String
    var primaryID: Int
}

class B {
    var kind: String
    var primaryID: Int
}
```

I have these collections:

```
var setOfA: Set<A>
var arrayOfB: Array<B>
```

I need to update `arrayOfB` with value from `setOfA`. For example iterate through `arrayOfB`, fetch the element from `setOfA` (where primaryID is equal) and update the `arrayOfB`.

Would look like:

```
for bElement in arrayOfB {
    let a = setOfA.first(where: { $0.primaryID == bElement.primaryID })
    bElement.kind = a.name // Just an example
}
```

If the efficiency of `first(where:)` is O(n) (I don't really know), the code above is O(n^2) (given both collections are same length).

The one thing I can think of, is removing each element of the `set` I fetch, there by reducing the inner cycle by half.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `first(where:)` traverses the collection until a matching
element is found, so the complexity of your approach is limited by
the *product* of the number of elements of the array and the set.

This is what I would do: Create a *dictionary* first which maps each
primary id to its corresponding element from `setOfA`:

```
var idToA: [Int: A] = [:]
for a in setOfA {
    idToA[a.primaryID] = a
}
```

Then traverse `arrayOfB`, look up the id in the dictionary, and update
the element if necessary:

```
for b in arrayOfB {
    if let a = idToA[b.primaryID] {
        b.kind = a.name
    }
}
```

This requires a single traversal of both `setOfA` and `arrayOfB`,
plus the dictionary lookups. (And dictionary lookups are fast if 
there are few collisions on the key hashes, which is the case for
integer keys.)